# Can you recommend a good extension we can use for Magento 2 to auto complete address during checkout?

Tags: shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address, checkout-page, address

I'm looking for an extension that we could use in our store to autocomplete the address during checkout so there will be less mistakes when customer's enter their address?

I've tried to research some options but the ones that I found are integrated in their Checkout extension which we don't want since we're happy with our current checkout page. We just want to add the feature of auto completing the address.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some extension :

1. https://marketplace.magento.com/shipperhq-module-address-autocomplete.html
2. https://www.magepal.com/address-autocomplete-for-magento-2.html
3. https://www.magearray.com/google-address-auto-complete-extension-for-magento-2.html
4. https://github.com/shipperhq/module-address-autocomplete

Check the demo and screenshot and select according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is for free.

Plugin for Magento Store- https://marketplace.magento.com/ginbox-smartaddress.html

Steps to integrate GINBOX's Plugin

Create business account to get credentials-  https://www.ginbox.io/accounts/
GINBOX Plugin Integration Steps- https://docs.ginbox.io